# Can't get information about another object

Tags: trigger, soql, lookup

Hello I try build a trigger, this trigger fire in the register object, and when its create send the information to times object, but before insert the data in time object, have to testing if the Project object have the Project Pm field different of null.

I try to do this code but doesn't work.

I did this steps.

1. Create a trigger with object and instantiate
2. Create a list to object were I want send the data Registo->Time
3. With Select find the field Projecto_PM__c in object Projectos__c and compare if is the same selected in a lookup in Registo__c object
4. Compare if Projecto_PM__c is different from null
5. And insert data in Time object

   ```
   trigger updatetime on Registo__c (After insert) {

       for (Registo__c registo : Trigger.New) {
           List<Milestone1_Time__c> sr = new List<Milestone1_Time__c>();

           Projectos__c test = [SELECT Id, Projecto_PM__c FROM Projectos__c WHERE Name = :registo.Projecto_associado__c];

           if (test.Projecto_PM__c != NULL) {
               sr.add(new Milestone1_Time__c(
                      Description__c = registo.Descricao__c,
                      Hours__c = registo.Numero_de_horas_dispendidas__c,
                      Date__c = registo.Data_da_tarefa__c,
                      Project_Task__c = registo.task_relacao__c
               ));
           }
           insert sr;
   ```

Somebody can help me with this, I'm new in apex and don't know the next step.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that the code above doesn't work? Can you be a bit more specific about what you thing has to happen but doesn't happen?

Comment: I want if the Projecto_PM__c have data the data insert in the new data in registo__c create a new record i Time object.
Because when you create a new record in registo__c you have  a lookup to choose the Project(Projecto__c) so, if the project have data in field Projecto_PM__c insert the information in new record in Time object.

Comment: Are you saying Registo__c object has a lookup field on Projecto__c object? What is the name of that field?

Comment: The object Registo__c have one lookup to Project__c. The field name(Lookup) in Registo__c is Projecto_associado__c

Comment: Lisyy - you are doing SOQL selects within a for loop - not best practice -- you'll hit governor limits in bulk operations.  Go and read: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/04/20/writing-bulk-triggers-for-salesforce/ or search on 'salesforce trigger bulk best practices'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things that stand out in the code above:

1. Don't do SOQL queries or DML operations in the loop body
2. You say you have a lookup from `Registo__c` to `Projectos__c`, in that case you should be comparing it with `Id` and not `Name` field of `Projectos__c`

Have a look at the code below:

```
trigger updatetime on Registo__c (After insert) {

    List<Milestone1_Time__c> sr = new List<Milestone1_Time__c>();
    List<Id> projectoIds = new List<Id>();

    for (Registo__c registo : Trigger.New) {
        projectoIds.add(registo.Projecto_associado__c);
    }

    Map<Id, Projectos__c> projectos = new Map<Id, Projectos__c>([SELECT Projecto_PM__c FROM Projectos__c WHERE Id in :projectoIds]);

    for (Registo__c registo : Trigger.New) {
        if (projectos.get(registo.Projecto_associado__c).Projecto_PM__c != NULL) {
            sr.add(new Milestone1_Time__c(
                   Description__c = registo.Descricao__c,
                   Hours__c = registo.Numero_de_horas_dispendidas__c,
                   Date__c = registo.Data_da_tarefa__c,
                   Project_Task__c = registo.task_relacao__c
            ));
        }
    }
    insert sr;
```

Comment: Dumb question. You can explain that lines please

projectoIds.add(registo.Projecto_associado__c);

Map<Id, Projectos__c> projectos = new Map<Id, Projectos__c>([SELECT Projecto_PM__c FROM Projectos__c WHERE Id in :projectoIds]); Why map?

 if (projectos.get(registo.Projecto_associado__c).Projecto_PM__c != NULL) and here I tried use get in another time and doesn't work, you can me explain specifically why to use.

I know I have to study more Apex. :)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Reason I'm storing Projects in Map is so that when I iterate over List of `Registro__c` objects passed to the Trigger (`Trigger.new`) I can easily get Project that is related to each of `Registro__c`s by executing `projectos.get(registo.Projecto_associado__c)`. Nothing to do with Apex - just common sense. Also pay attention to Eric's solution - I missed important check. Before trying to retrieve Project via `projectos.get(registo.Projecto_associado__c)` you should first check that `projectos` Map contains the key are looking for: `if(projectos.containsKey(registo.Projecto_associado__c)){...`

Answer (score 0):

Just following your code you could do this:

```
trigger updatetime on Registo__c (After insert) {

Set<ID> projectosIDs = New Set<ID>();

for(Registo__c registo : trigger.new){
     projectosIDs.add(registo.Projecto_associado__c);
}

Map<ID,Progectos__c> proj = New Map<ID<Projectos_c>([Select ID, Projecto_PM__c From Projectos__c Where ID IN : projectosIDs]);

Milestone1_Time__c[] sr = New Milestone1_Time__c[]{};

for(Registo__c registo: Trigger.New) {
if(proj.containsKey(registo.Projecto_associado__c)){
  if(prom.get(registo.Projecto_associado__c).Projecto_PM__c != null){
  sr.add(new Milestone1_Time__c(
        Description__c = registo.Descricao__c,
        Hours__c = registo.Numero_de_horas_dispendidas__c,
        Date__c = registo.Data_da_tarefa__c,
        Project_Task__c = registo.task_relacao__c
        )); 
  }
}

if(!sr.isEmpty())
insert sr;
}
```